# I am stepping down as a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have made the decision to step down as a moderator on Korea.SE. My work schedule has made it difficult for me to remain active enough on this site to be a productive moderator. I still will remain as a normal user of the site and will contribute where I can.

Thank you for making Korean.SE a success so far. Here's to a great future on Korean.SE

Comment: Not good news but I'm sure everyone appreciates all your efforts to date! Are the community managers appointing someone else at some point?

Comment: @topomorto Yes, there should be a new mod appointed I believe. Thank you for your amazing work here. You have really helped make this site successful.

Comment: sad to hear that you are stepping down as moderator but I also hope that you will be able to continue helping our site to graduation. I wish you success in your offline endeavors as well.